# Azure IoT SDK for C with WolfSSL and STM32

Tags: gsm, tls1.2, stm32f4, azure-iot-sdk, wolfssl

I am trying to port Azure IoT SDKs for C to STM32 controller. I am using wolfSSL library for TLS version 1.2 and I am able to build the code successfully in OpenSTM32 environment.

But, after establishing successful connection with Azure server, I am unable to establish TLS handshake with the server.
I am using OpenSTM32’s example user_settings.h file from wolfSSL library to build wolfSSL library.

Do I need to make any additional changes in the WolfSSL library to use it with Azure?

OR

Is there any other TLS library, which can be used with Azure IoT SDK for C and STM32 controller?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/wolfSSL/wolfMQTT/tree/master/examples/azure) is a WolfSSL MQTT sample for connecting to Azure IoT Hub you can reference. What's your STM32 device, Nucleo-F401RE or Cloud-JAM?

Comment: We are using STM32F413.
Actually we want to use Azure IoT SDKs at the higher level because, using reported properties, desired properties or methods reception will be easy with them.

Comment: For using SDK you can check [this tutorial](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-device-ecosystem/blob/master/get_started/stm32cube-stm32nucleo-c.md). It uses stm32f401.

Comment: The same question posted [here](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f873c5c9-6bdd-4dcd-a34d-43fa0d4e8777/azure-iot-sdks-for-c-with-wolfssl-and-stm32?forum=azureiothub) in MSDN. We will add the following updates to MSDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get it working.

There were issues with the buffer sizes and server timeouts.

Increasing the buffer size and optimizing the sending logic solved the issue.

Now, I am able to access every functionality of Azure IoT SDK for C !